# Rails ajax: Help creating text preivew auto_html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I create an preview field for auto_html?

My controller:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end

def preview
  post = Post.new(params[:comment])
  render :text => post.body_html
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :titel %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :titel %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body_html %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body_html %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :up_votes %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :up_votes %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :down_votes %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :down_votes %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div id="post-preview" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black; height:500px;"></div>
```

I want to make an preview of the title and the body_html.
Example the a user types "Hello helloe helloe" in the body_html text_area it would instant gets previewed in a div below.

There was an example of this feature here: http://rors.org/2010/08/15/auto_html.html 
But it does not work anymore.

Comment: Depending on how complex your use–case is, I'd suggest doing this entirely on the client–side. Especially if you want to update on key-stroke events.

Comment: How is that done with Jquery?

Comment: It depends ;) — Can we assume that you have a textbox and want to preview underneath whatever text **and** HTML the user inputs? No markdown or textile or something similar? (I'm not familiar with auto_html, FYI.)

Comment: I want to preview whatever the user types. But it should be viewed as auto_html. That means that if the user types a link auto_html makes it automatic a link or if a user paste a URL from youtube it automatic gets embeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it on the client-side, just use an onfocus on the textbox element which will create an event listener. This function will set another event listener which will activate on keydown and activate another function. This final function will run whenever the user types something, and will access the contents of the textbox and put it into the preview div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keypressed(form) {
  text = form.textbox.value
  //do any processing on text desired
  preview.innerHTML = text; 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="blah.cgi">
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" onkeydown="keypressed(this.form);"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<br />
<br />
<div id="preview">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sending it off to the server is amazingly inefficient, unless you're doing syntax highliting, in which case you could send it off every 10 seconds or so.

P.S. By the way, if you want to do the auto_html stuff, you can occasionally send it off to the server to do that.